# Accessing web UI API through Jubyter notebook on Runpod

Tags: python, cloud

I am trying to make a dataset using a script by Aemon-Algiz. it works fine on my laptop but when I try the same steps on Runpod. I always get Non JSON responses and it skips all chunks. Please help me out.

[image]

I tried using the other open ports as well but the result was same. I had an error if I interrupt the script.

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 163
    160     print("Processing complete.")
    162 # Call the function with the desired folder path
--> 163 process_pdfs_in_folder('/workspace/Datasets')

Cell In[33], line 151, in process_pdfs_in_folder(folder_path)
    148 token_chunks = list(chunks(tokens, 256))
    150 for chunk in token_chunks:
--> 151     response = submit_to_api(tokenizer.decode(chunk))
    152     if response is not None:
    153         append_to_json_file(response)

Cell In[33], line 82, in submit_to_api(chunk, retries)
     80 for i in range(retries + 1):  # +1 to account for the initial attempt
     81     try:
---> 82         response = run(command + chunk.strip(), history)
     83         if is_json(response):
     84             print(response)

Cell In[33], line 49, in run(user_input, history)
      7 def run(user_input, history):
      8     request = {
      9         'user_input': user_input,
     10         'history': history,
   (...)
     46         'stopping_strings': []
     47     }
---> 49     response = requests.post(URI, json=request)
     51     result = response.json()['results'][0]['history']
     52     return result['visible'][-1][1]

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py:115, in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    103 def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    104     r"""Sends a POST request.
    105 
    106     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
    112     :rtype: requests.Response
    113     """
--> 115     return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py:486, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    483     timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
    485 try:
--> 486     resp = conn.urlopen(
    487         method=request.method,
    488         url=url,
    489         body=request.body,
    490         headers=request.headers,
    491         redirect=False,
    492         assert_same_host=False,
    493         preload_content=False,
    494         decode_content=False,
    495         retries=self.max_retries,
    496         timeout=timeout,
    497         chunked=chunked,
    498     )
    500 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:
    501     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:790, in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    773 # Try to detect a common user error with proxies which is to
    774 # set an HTTP proxy to be HTTPS when it should be 'http://'
    775 # (ie {'http': 'http://proxy', 'https': 'https://proxy'})
    776 # Instead we add a nice error message and point to a URL.
    777 if (
    778     isinstance(e, BaseSSLError)
    779     and self.proxy
   (...)
    782     and conn.proxy.scheme == "https"
    783 ):
    784     e = ProxyError(
    785         "Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, "
    786         "try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: "
    787         "https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html"
    788         "#https-proxy-error-http-proxy",
    789         SSLError(e),
--> 790     )
    791 elif isinstance(e, (BaseSSLError, CertificateError)):
    792     e = SSLError(e)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:536, in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    529         port = None
    531     return (scheme, host, port) == (self.scheme, self.host, self.port)
    533 def urlopen(
    534     self,
    535     method,
--> 536     url,
    537     body=None,
    538     headers=None,
    539     retries=None,
    540     redirect=True,
    541     assert_same_host=True,
    542     timeout=_Default,
    543     pool_timeout=None,
    544     release_conn=None,
    545     chunked=False,
    546     body_pos=None,
    547     **response_kw
    548 ):
    549     """
    550     Get a connection from the pool and perform an HTTP request. This is the
    551     lowest level call for making a request, so you'll need to specify all
   (...)
    639         :meth:`urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.from_httplib`
    640     """
    642     parsed_url = parse_url(url)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py:461, in getresponse(self)
    450     assert_fingerprint(
    451         self.sock.getpeercert(binary_form=True), self.assert_fingerprint
    452     )
    453 elif (
    454     context.verify_mode != ssl.CERT_NONE
    455     and not getattr(context, "check_hostname", False)
   (...)
    459     # the TLS library, this cannot always be done. So we check whether
    460     # the TLS Library still thinks it's matching hostnames.
--> 461     cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
    462     if not cert.get("subjectAltName", ()):
    463         warnings.warn(
    464             (
    465                 "Certificate for {0} has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a "
   (...)
    470             SubjectAltNameWarning,
    471         )

File /usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1375, in HTTPConnection.getresponse(self)
   1373 try:
   1374     try:
-> 1375         response.begin()
   1376     except ConnectionError:
   1377         self.close()

File /usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:318, in HTTPResponse.begin(self)
    316 # read until we get a non-100 response
    317 while True:
--> 318     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    319     if status != CONTINUE:
    320         break

File /usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:279, in HTTPResponse._read_status(self)
    278 def _read_status(self):
--> 279     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    280     if len(line) > _MAXLINE:
    281         raise LineTooLong("status line")

File /usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py:705, in SocketIO.readinto(self, b)
    703 while True:
    704     try:
--> 705         return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    706     except timeout:
    707         self._timeout_occurred = True

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.